# Installing handlatex in miktex 2.9

Tags: fonts, errors, installing, miktex

I’ve been trying to get handlatex (http://code.google.com/p/handlatex/) to work with miktex 2.9 and texnicCenter on windows 7.  I tried copying it in the miktex directories: tex/latex and tex/xelatex without success. Unfortunatly I was not successful finding any hints on google. The latex code I’m using right now is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, titlepage,]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lowwordangle=-3,highwordangle=3]{hand}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\section*{\texttt{hand}\LaTeX\ Demo}

\vfill

\begin{handpar}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis ut libero et arcu interdum varius. Nam bibendum, mi sed consequat malesuada, nunc diam condimentum massa, sit amet egestas nibh ligula sit amet dui. Vestibulum eu urna. Etiam vestibulum. Aenean nisi nulla, fringilla at, laoreet eu, iaculis id, diam. Mauris aliquet vehicula lacus. Maecenas id nisl ac justo sodales dictum. Phasellus eget eros. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam ut tortor vitae dui mollis egestas. Nullam sagittis libero quis nibh. Donec aliquam. Donec tincidunt. Aliquam eget nisl. Suspendisse mollis pellentesque nunc.

\end{handpar}

\vfill

\noindent $\blacksquare$

\end{document}
```

This is the error Message I’m getting:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `hand.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
```

It would be great if somebody could tell me how to install handlatex correctly in miktex.
Greetings
betlor

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You might want to have a look at the MikTeX documentation: http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html

Comment: I'm going with the dupe here: there's nothing special about the package concerned, it's the usual local-install business.